# Array to string conversion in laravel DB conection

Tags: sql, arrays, string, laravel

I am trying to fix a problematic code caused array to string conversion, but I can't find the problem.

It's a plugin's config code from a program called "blessing-skin", I have tried to modify multiple arrays but it is invalid.

```
<?php
  $targetDbConfigForm = Option::form('connection', 'database setting', function ($form) {
    $form->text('forum_db_config[host]',     'TargetSqlAddress')->hint('There may be a delay in interfacing between database hosts, so please be aware.');
    $form->text('forum_db_config[port]',     'port');
    $form->text('forum_db_config[database]', 'database');
    $form->text('forum_db_config[username]', 'username');
    $form->text('forum_db_config[password]', 'password');
    $form->text('forum_db_config[table]',    'table');
    $form->select('forum_duplicated_prefer', 'duplicated prefer')
      ->option('remote', 'Use remote data')
      ->option('local',  'Use local data')
      ->description('After this selection, if the user data (such as the same user name and different username and password) conflicts, the option you choose will be used, and the user data of the other party will be overwritten.');
  })->handle()->always(function ($form) {
    $config = request('forum_db_config');
    if ($config) {
      option(['forum_db_config' => serialize($config)]);
    } else {
      $config = @unserialize(option('forum_db_config'));
    }
    config(['database.connections.remote' => array_merge(
      forum_get_default_db_config(), (array) $config
    )]);
    try {
      DB::connection('remote')->getPdo();
      if (Schema::connection('remote')->hasTable($config['table'])) {
        $form->addMessage('Connected', 'success');
      } else {
        $form->addMessage("Connected to databse，but table [{$config['table']}] not found.", 'warning');
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $form->addMessage('Cannot connect to MySQL server. <br>Error info: '.$e->getMessage(), 'danger');
    }
  });
?>
```

Find the reason for array to string conversion.

Comment: Please share the error that you're getting

Comment: https://i.loli.net/2019/05/25/5ce8fe4b2053554965.png